# -> operator in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, operator-keyword

Can anyone explain to me why (full code to follow) why:

```
printf("%d\n", S[2].Str->Str->Var); = 8
```

but

```
printf("%d\n", S[2].Str->Var); = 4
```

considering pointers take 8 bytes and the address of each is 8 bytes apart?

Full Code from Practice Exam Question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct S {
    int Var;
    struct S *Str;
};
int main(void) {
    struct S S[] = { { 8, NULL }, { 4, &S[0] }, { 2, &S[1] } };
    //array positions: 0,0  0,1     1,0  1,1      2,0   2,1
    printf("%d\n\n", S[2]); // = 2
    printf("%d\n", S[2].Str->Str->Var); // = 8

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The contents of S[2] points to [S1] which contents points to [S0] and that's that. It has nothing to do with size of pointers. Studying and writing obscure code like this isn't very meaningful.

Comment: You don't use any `sizeof` operator. Where should the size of pointers be taken into account and why?

Comment: What did you expect as output?

Comment: `printf("%d\n\n", S[2]); // = 2` That looks like undefined behaviour. `%d` expects a single integer parameter. Not a struct.

Comment: The question doesn't mention addition, so I removed "addition" from the title. You can [edit] your question if you want to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see struct S S[] is an array of structures.
An array of any type can be accessed by value with S[0]..S[i-1] where i is the length of the the array.
Inside each structure you have a pointer and an integer.Think the pointer as an arrow to the specific data structure.As you can see a pointer points to a specific memory location.In this example you have:

```
{ 8, NULL }, { 4, &S[0] }, { 2, &S[1] }
```

In S[2] the value of pointer Str is assigned to point to the memory location of S[1] and the str in S[1] to the memory location of S[0].
Its like traversing back.

Pseudocode:

```
S[2].Str -> S[1] 
S[1].Str -> S[0]
S[0].Var = 8

S[2].Str->Str->Var = 8
```

***The arrow (->) means access  value members of a structure through a pointer.***

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the pointers that are assigned at each element of the array.

Let's put it this way:

What you have here is the following:
Being each "tuple" the following: 
**(address of the indexed element, intValue, Str pointer value);** 
[(@1, 8, NULL), (@2, 4, @1), (@3, 2, @2)]

Now let's analyze the statement step by step:

```
S[2].Str // is actually the element at the 1º position of the array. (0 based indexing)
S[2].Str->Str // is pointing to the first element of the array (0th position)
S[2].Str->Str->Var // is accessing the value of the first element of the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the array `S` contains a singly-linked list the head of which is stored in the element `S[2]`.

That is the list look like

```
     Str       Str
S[2] ---> S[1] ---> S[0]
head
```

You can even introduce the name `head` the following way

```
struct S *head = &S[2];
```

So the list contains three nodes:

```
head -> head->Str -> head->Str->Str
S[2] -> S[1]      -> S[0]
```

So the call

```
printf("%d\n\n", S[2]->Var );
```

outputs the value `2` stored in the node `S[2]` (head)

```
printf("%d\n\n", S[2]->Str->Var );
```

outputs the value stored `4` in the node `S[1]` and

```
printf("%d\n\n", S[2]->Str->Str->Var );
```

outputs the value stored `8` in the node `S[01]`.